# How to get the tag name given the value in python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, minidom

My xml file looks similar to this

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder|Remind|Remain</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

I want the tag name when a string is given. For example if I specify string like '|', I want the tag i.e **heading.** How can I achieve this in python ?

Comment: Have u got ur solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler try may be-

```
import lxml.etree as et

s="""
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder|Remind|Remain</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
"""

tree = et.fromstring(s)

print tree.text
query = r'%s'%raw_input("Enter text: ")

pth = r'''//*[contains(text(),'%s')]'''%query

for t in tree.xpath(pth):
    print t.tag
```

If `|` is given as input then it prints `heading`.